# Using PHP variables in HTML

Tags: php, html

Evening all,

I have a reprogramming issue and would love some assistance

```
<div style="width:800px;height:100px;border:2px solid black;">
<html>
<body>
<br>
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password!") or die (mysql_error());
#echo "Connected to MYSQL ";
mysql_select_db("starforg_search") or die (mysql_error());
#echo "Connected to Data Base";
$query = "SELECT * FROM addserver";
$result = mysql_query ($query) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $value = $row['servername'];
        $value2 = $row['serveraddress'];
        $value3 = $row['portnumber'];
        $value4 = $row['description'];

}


?>

&nbsp;Server Name :<?php echo $_POST[$value1]; ?> 

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Server Address : <?php echo $_POST[$value2]; ?>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Port Number : <?php echo $_POST[$value3]; ?>
<br>
<br>
&nbsp;Server Description : <?php echo $_POST[$value4]; ?>
<br>
<br>

// Script by Akensai

<?php
$ip = $_POST[$value];
$port = $_POST[$value2];

if (!$socket = @fsockopen($ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30))
{
 echo "&nbsp;<font color='red'><CENTRE><strong>Server Is Offline!</strong></CENTRE></font>";
}
else 
{
 echo "&nbsp;<font color='green'><CENTRE><strong> Server Is Online!</strong></CENTRE></font>";  

  fclose($socket);
}
?>
<p>&nbsp;Server status is updated every hour</p>
<br>
</body>
</html> 
</div>
```

**This is the output**

[image]
needless to say i want the values from the PHP script to be added to the HTML fields

It works fine if i just echo and call the PHP values from Mysql so i must have some HTML syntax errors please correct if possible.

Thanks for your time

Ben

Comment: Summary: 'I have some code and you need to fix it.' Please read "[ask]" to make good questions. Some tips on your code: 1) don't use `<br>` and `$nbsp;` those are bad practises, use CSS margin/padding; 2) or die is not an error handling; 3) put the PHP logic at the top of your page; 4) don't put div elements before <html>; 5) you're missing a doctype.

Comment: 6) `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, use `PDO` or `mysqli_*`. 7) it's better to use separate `css` file than putting styles in `style` attribute. 8) tags should be lower-cased.

Comment: is this DB ($query = "SELECT * FROM addserver";) query executed in same page or another page..

Comment: if u are executed that query in a same page means why using this $_POST[$value] directly echo  the value of $value change this to **Server Name :<?php echo $_POST[$value1]; ?> to Server Name :<?php echo $value1; ?>** and re arrange in your code  Server Address : <?php echo $value2; ?> Port Number : <?php echo $value3; ?> Server Description : <?php echo $value4; ?>

Comment: @WouterJ i don't see how that was a bad question but ok...

Comment: @bennyboy: It's a bad question because it contains lots of code (MySQL connection, for example) which is completely irrelevant to the question asked (using PHP variables in HTML). It shows that you jumped from "it does not work" directly to "I'll post to SO.com", without putting any effort into it yourself. The redundant code probably also makes different errors show up on other people's systems (DB connection failure) instead of reliably reproducing your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to `echo $value1;` instead of `echo $_POST[$value1];`

Also, There is no `$value1`. If you want to retrieve your Server Name it should only be `$value`

The same concept should be applied for other values that you want to retrieve.

$_POST is used to collect values in a form with method="post" not to retrieve value from your SQL query

Comment: man all the votes down :/ haters gunna hate, Buutttt thank you for your response and time :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting values from URL ? If not, why are you using $_POST[...] ???

`Server Name :<?php echo $_POST[$value1]; ?>`

I guess you need to use it as just:

`Server Name :<?php echo $value1; ?>`

This should work for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

POST and GET are methods for passing variables from forms or through the URL. You declare your variables in this code, so just use `$value` not `$_POST[$value]`. You were looking for a POSTed variable with the name contained in `$value`.

Additionally, you shouldn't have `<div>` tags outside of the `<html>` tags.

This code should work.

```
<html>
<div style="width:800px;height:100px;border:2px solid black;">
<body>
<br>
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "starforg_forg13", "Tigger161!") or die (mysql_error());
#echo "Connected to MYSQL ";
mysql_select_db("starforg_search") or die (mysql_error());
#echo "Connected to Data Base";
$query = "SELECT * FROM addserver";
$result = mysql_query ($query) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $value1 = $row['servername'];
        $value2 = $row['serveraddress'];
        $value3 = $row['portnumber'];
        $value4 = $row['description'];

}

?>

&nbsp;Server Name :<?php echo $value1; ?> 

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Server Address : <?php echo $value2; ?>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Port Number : <?php echo $value3; ?>
<br>
<br>
&nbsp;Server Description : <?php echo $value4; ?>
<br>
<br>

// Script by Akensai

<?php
$ip = $value;
$port = $value2;

if (!$socket = @fsockopen($ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30))
{
 echo "&nbsp;<font color='red'><CENTRE><strong>Server Is Offline!</strong></CENTRE></font>";
}
else 
{
 echo "&nbsp;<font color='green'><CENTRE><strong> Server Is Online!</strong></CENTRE></font>";  

  fclose($socket);
}
?>
<p>&nbsp;Server status is updated every hour</p>
<br>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have corrected the code and I hope this will work for you..

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>
    Server-Info
    </title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div style="width:800px;height:100px;border:2px solid black;">
    <br>
    <?php

    mysql_connect("localhost", "starforg_forg13", "Tigger161!") or die (mysql_error());
    #echo "Connected to MYSQL ";
    mysql_select_db("starforg_search") or die (mysql_error());
    #echo "Connected to Data Base";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM addserver";
    $result = mysql_query ($query) or die (mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $value = $row['servername'];
            $value2 = $row['serveraddress'];
            $value3 = $row['portnumber'];
            $value4 = $row['description'];

    }


    ?>

    &nbsp;Server Name :<?php echo $value; ?> 

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Server Address : <?php echo $value2; ?>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Port Number : <?php echo $value3; ?>
    <br>
    <br>
    &nbsp;Server Description : <?php echo $value4; ?>
    <br>
    <br>

    // Script by Akensai

    <?php
    $ip = $value;
    $port = $value2;

    if (!$socket = @fsockopen($ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30))
    {
     echo "&nbsp;<font color='red'><CENTRE><strong>Server Is Offline!</strong></CENTRE></font>";
    }
    else 
    {
     echo "&nbsp;<font color='green'><CENTRE><strong> Server Is Online!</strong></CENTRE></font>";  

      fclose($socket);
    }
    ?>
    <p>&nbsp;Server status is updated every hour</p>
    <br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```